# Dataframe group by the studentid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the students and order the students by the counts and print the top 3. I tried it with:

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('studentid')['studentid'].transform('count')
df_new = df.sort_values('freq')
print("The 3 students")
print(df_new[['freq', 'studentname', 'studentid']])
```

But the output is every time the same. The output only shows me the normal data frame with the frequency, but doesn't  groupt it. How could I group the dataframe?

My dataframe

```
    d = {'Studentid ': [1, 2, 3 , 1, 1, 3], 'Studentname': ['Bob', 'Jason', 'Jackson', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Jackson'], 'project': ['X2', 'P75', 'P741' , 'O51', 'Q874', 'P8745']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

     Studentid  Studentname   project
0            1  Bob           X2       
1            2  Jason         P75
2            3  Jackson       P741
4            1  Bob           O51
7            1  Bob           Q874
6            3  Jackson       P8745
```

What I want

```
     Studentid  Studentname   freq_of_projects
0            1  Bob           3
1            3  Jackson       2
2            2  Jason         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

You can use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and then [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['Studentid','Studentname'])
        .size()
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index(name='freq_of_projects'))
print (df)
   Studentid Studentname  freq_of_projects
0          1         Bob                 3
1          3     Jackson                 2
2          2       Jason                 1
```

Comment: Thanks again for your quick answer! Is there still a possibility that I don't sort according to the `index` but according to the value `freq_of_projects`? My output shows me that it sorted by index.

Comment: @IgotYouLiketheGoat - If add `df = df.sort_values('freq')` it is what you need?

Comment: Yes, but if I add this 
then again he does not group. :/

Comment: @IgotYouLiketheGoat - Super, I see data was changed, what is expcted output from new data?

Comment: The new output is that he outputs the number and double enumerates students, so he does not group.
I would like to have the number of projects by a student sorted by the highest frequenzy.

Comment: @IgotYouLiketheGoat - I am sample man ;) So is possible add expected output from new saple data? I think it is different like old data sample expected output.

Comment: @IgotYouLiketheGoat - If think I got it, can you check edit?

Comment: You were faster than me! Your last edit was it! Perfect, thank you very much for your efforts and time. Wish you a nice day! :)